# Calculating r.li.shannon with vector grid on GRASS GIS

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, qgis-grass-plugin

I looked up [baker and cai (1992)](https://github.com/mauriciovancine/GRASS-GIS-Landscape-Metrics/blob/main/articles/baker_cai_1992.pdf) and throughout the internet to find my answer, but my novice level makes it hard to find concrete solutions.

I am trying to calculate the shannon diversity index ([r.li.shannon](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass-stable/manuals/r.li.shannon.html)) for a landscape in GRASS GIS 7.8.7. My input file is a raster of my different land covers with an assigned number for each class (similar to Corine Land Cover). I work with Windows 10. I have a 1 per 1 kilometer grid.

I want to know the heterogeneity in each square to be able to vectorize that information and select squares which are heterogenous.

I've tried using the r.li.shannon on GRASS GIS, but the only sampling framework allowed is a moving window configuration ; which I've tried but the results are too detailed for me to be able to consider them in a grid later one (see below).

[image: shannon diversity index calculated on my study site]

In QGIS, I've tried the plugin LecoS, but to no avail as the r.li.shannon needs a moving window configuration file either way.
Which confuses me a lot since baker and cai (1992) wrote about sampling frameworks and used a whole map framework in one of their analyses but perhaps i'm confused or things changed since then.

Is there a way to actually calculate the shannon diversity index in grids, either in GRASS GIS or QGIS?

Comment: AFAIK you need to have a binary map, i.e. thematically split your input raster map of different land covers into separate maps, then analyze those with r.li.shannon.

Comment: @markusN thank you for your input. i don't know if i explained myself very well.
from my understanding of the r.li tool and my tries with FRAGSTATS, it makes me wonder whether that would actually give me what i want to achieve...

what i want is a measure of heterogeneity by mesh of 1km² each. 

whether i work with GRASS GIS or FRAGSTATS, i can't seem to calculate the shannon diversity index in each mesh. i was wondering whether that was actually possible or not.
thank you very much.

Comment: a solution i've found is to calculate the shannon diversity index for my landscape with a moving window configuration and to select pixels in the raster calculator above a certain value from the output raster file ; and then vectorize these values to "identify" areas where the heterogeneity is higher... i don't know if it's a viable solution, but it's the best i've found so far